# What's the strictest definition of randomness?

Tags: statistics, definition, random

I've heard that there are several different ways to define randomness. If so, what is the strictest definition of randomness that are widely accepted as defining a type or sort of randomness. By strictest, I mean the one with the most 'strict' requirements. I don't want to define what I mean by 'strict', because I don't know how many definitions there are, and if defining it would make the question hard to answer.

I am also interested in what result or distribution the definition would yield for a large number A.

Comment: Can you at least give a couple of examples, so we can have a hint about what you are after?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by an example?

Comment: Maybe this relates to your question, as there are ways to examine sets and determined (according to some rules) how random the elements are. If you investigate the rules, you may be able to arrive to an answer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness_tests

Comment: You don't want to define "strictness", but maybe you can give us  a hint of what you have in mind by some other means, such as by an example.  To get meaningful help with your question you should formulate it so we can understand what it is.

Comment: The strictest definition is the one that matches the lowest number of candidates.

Answer (score 3):

There are many definitions of randomness, based on equal probability of each value and the lack of correlations among values (at every scale), and such.

Perhaps the "strictest" definition is due to Kolmogorov:  a string (e.g., of characters or bits) is random if and only if it is shorter than any computer program that can produce that string.

There are some methodological challenges to making Kolmogorov's definition practical in every case, and it presumes some very deep properties about the universality of computation, but conceptually it has much to recommend it.